# Why interval created on object survive after object reference deletion

Tags: javascript, object, garbage-collection, setinterval

I don't understand why a `setInterval`, which is done in a object, persist after the object was destroyed.

I thought it'll be catched by the garbage collector as well as the object itself, once destroyed any reference, but apparently not...
Can you explain that?

A concrete example pastable directly in console:

```
class List {
  constructor() {
    this.elts = [];
  }

  add(elt) {
    this.elts.push(elt);
  }

  remove(elt) {
    this.elts = this.elts.filter(e => e!== elt);
  }
}

class Elt {
  constructor() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('alive')
    }, 1000);
  }
}

const list = new List();

function test() {
  const elt = new Elt();
  list.add(elt);
  setTimeout(() => {
    list.remove(elt);
  }, 3000);
}
```

When calling the `test()` function, the "alive" log should only be displayed 3 times; after 3 turns, the "elt" object is removed from the "list" object, so no more references point to it. I though that the garbage collector should do its job and the interval should die with "elt" ...

But it is not the case, the interval still survives and turns again :/

Any tips ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does setInterval inside an object prevent garbage collection, when the object is deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429030/does-setinterval-inside-an-object-prevent-garbage-collection-when-the-object-is)

Comment: Almost, but my interval callback doesn't contains any pointer in my example ; I think the closure is the key but I don't understand how it internally works

Comment: The answer to that question implies that event listeners and intervals have to be removed in order for their callback function to be released.

Comment: Hmm yes, but I can also read : "the function created by this.update.bind(this) (which in turn has a reference to the object, keeping it in memory).". That's not my case, simple callback withotu any reference to anything

Comment: Yes, that means that the `Elt` instance may be garbage collected but the interval won't stop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval by doing `clearInterval(this.interval)`

```js
class List {
  constructor() {
    this.elts = [];
  }

  add(elt) {
    this.elts.push(elt);
  }

  remove(elt) {
    elt.stop();
    this.elts = this.elts.filter(e => e !== elt);
  }
}

class Elt {
  constructor() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('alive')
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

const list = new List();

function test() {
  const elt = new Elt();
  list.add(elt);
  setTimeout(() => {
    list.remove(elt);
  }, 3100); // increased to 3100 so it has time to execute 3 times
}

test();
```

Comment: Thanks, obviously I can manually destroy the interval, but my question is why ? Why it survives without any reference ?

Comment: You're creating `elt` as a stand-alone object first. Then you append it and, after a while, remove it again, but it still exists outside of `list`.

Comment: You mean the "const elt = ..." ? It only exist in the "test" function context, yes ? It's not a global variable, so when "test" function is done, it should be considered as "garbageable"

Comment: `setInterval()` just creates a function to run every so often. By setting `Elk.interval` to it you only obtain a reference (to possibly stop it), but beyond that it runs on its own - not related to `Elk`. So even if the object doesn't exist anymore the function will keep on executing, until you stop it.

Comment: Your comment is the answer :)